# Making a footer float properly with CSS

Tags: html, css, navigation, footer

I want the two headers (navigation and download links) to float side by 
side. Additionally, the navigation items (home, solutions, about, 
 contact) and the linked images to float directly below their headers 
(navigation and download links). I am fairly new at this so any assistance is greatly appreciated!

```css
body, html{
font-family: helvetica;
height:100%;
margin:0%;
}

header {
padding: 20px 0;
background: white;
}

.container {
padding: 0 30px 00px 30px;
max-width: 1600px; /* look on big monitor for width */
margin-right: 20px;
}

.logo-box {
float: left;
}

.logo-box a {
outline: none;
display: inline-block;
}

.logo-box img {display: inline;}
nav {
overflow: hidden;
}

ul {
list-style: none;
margin: 0;
padding-top: 30px;
padding-bottom: 0px;
float: right;
}

nav li {
display: inline-block;
margin-left: 25px;
height: 20px;
line-height: 20px;
transition: .5s linear;
}

nav a {
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
position: relative;
color: black;
font-size: 12px;
font-weight: lighter;
text-transform: uppercase;
}

nav a:after {
content: "";
width:0;
height: 7.5px;
position: absolute;
left: 0;
bottom: 0px;
background: black;
transition: width .3s linear;
}

nav a:hover:after {
width: 100%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 660px) {
header {text-align: center;}
.logo-box {
float: none;
display: inline-block;
margin: 0 0 0 0;
}
ul {float: none;}
nav li:first-of-type {margin-right: 0;}
}

@media screen and (max-width: 550px) {
nav {overflow: visible;}
nav li {
display: block;
margin: 0;
height: 40px;
line-height: 40px;
}
nav li:hover {text-decoration: underline;}
nav a:after {content: none;}
}

.heroImage {
background-image: url("./images/doc_tablet2.jpeg");
background-position: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
border-top: 1px solid gray;
position: relative;
width: 100%;
height: 70%;
display: table;
}

.heroText {
margin-top: 160px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
width: 70%;
text-align: center;
padding: 20px;
border-radius: 5px;
border-width: medium;
left: 0;
font-family: helvetica;
font-weight: lighter;
font-size: 20px;
color: #333;
letter-spacing: 1px;
display:block;
}

#heroTextButtons {
display: inline-block;
padding: 20px;
text-align: center;
font-size: 1px;
font: helvetica;
font-weight: lighter;
text-align: center;
color: #2D71C5;
}


/* End main image section */

/* Why choose us section start */
.whyChooseUs {
margin-left: 25px;
padding: 10px 40px;
height: auto;
width: auto;
color: #333;
letter-spacing: 1px;
line-height: 30px;
position: relative;
text-align: center;
outline: none;
font-size: 18px;
display: block;
font-weight: lighter;
}
/* Why choose us section end */

/* Solution table start */
.solutionTable {
table-layout: fixed;
margin-bottom: 60px;
padding: auto;
height: auto;
width: 100%;
color: #333;
letter-spacing: 1px;
line-height: 25px;
position: relative;
text-align: center;
font-size: 18px;
overflow:auto;
display: block;
border-collapse: separate;
border-spacing: 2px;
}

.solutionTable th, td {
table-layout: fixed;
text-align: center;
color: #333;
letter-spacing: 1px;
font-size: 16px;
font-weight: lighter;
vertical-align: top;
width: auto;
padding: 5px 40px 0px 0px;
overflow: auto;
}

/* End of Why Choose Us */

/* Featured Clients Section #FAFAFA*/
.featuredClients {
text-align: center;
background-color: white;
border-radius: 0px;
width: 100%;
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: top;
border-top: solid;
border-bottom: solid;
border-color: #e9e9e9;
border-width: thin;
font-weight: lighter;
}

#featuredClientsText {
font: helvetica;
font-size: 35px;
color: #333;
font-weight:lighter, bold;
letter-spacing: 1px;
text-align: center;
padding: 30px;
margin-top: 20px;
}

.decorated {
 overflow: hidden;
 text-align: center;
 font-weight:100;
 }
.decorated > span{
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
}
.decorated > span:before, .decorated > span:after{
content: '';
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
border-bottom: 2px solid;
width: 150px; /* half of limiter */
margin: 0 20px;
}
.decorated > span:before{
right: 100%;
}
.decorated > span:after{
left: 100%;
}
.images{
text-align: center;
vertical-align: top;
display: inline-block;
padding: 20px;
}

/* End Featured Clients Section */
.findOut {
text-align: center;
color: #333;
font: helvetica;
font-size: 35px;
font-weight: lighter;
letter-spacing: 1px;
letter-spacing: 1px;
background-color: white;
padding: 60px 60px 70px 50px;
width: auto;
border-bottom-style: solid;
border-color: #333;
border-width: medium;
position: relative;
line-height: 50px;
background-color: #FAFAFA;
border-bottom-style: solid;
border-color: #333;
}

.learnMoreText{
font-size: 20px;
font: helvetica;
font-weight: lighter;
text-align: center;
color: #0070c9;

}
.learnMoreText:hover {
text-decoration: underline;
text-align: center;
}
/* Find Out How Section */

/*  Footer start */
#footerContainer {
float:right;
width:100%;
position:relative;
right:50%;
background-color: #dddddd; /* column 1 background color */
}

.nav {
font-size: 18px;
text-align: left;
font-family: helvetica;
margin-left: 40px;
letter-spacing: 1.5px;
color: #333;
}

#col1 {
float:left;
width:48%;
position:relative;
left:52%;
text-align: left;
text-decoration: none;
}

#col1 ul, li, a {
justify-content:space-around;
list-style-type:none;
font-size: 12px;
line-height: 25px;
text-decoration: none;
color: black;
letter-spacing: 1px;
}

#col1 a:hover {
color: black;
text-decoration: underline;
}

#col2 {
float:left;
width:50%;
position:relative;
left:52%;
background-color: #dddddd; /* column 2 background color */
text-decoration: none;
}

#col2 ul {
list-style: none;
list-style-type:none;
font-size: 20px;
padding: 15px;
text-align: left;
color: black;
text-decoration: none;
left: 52%;
}

#col2 li {
font-size: 20px;
text-align: left;
margin-right: 100px;
display: inline-block;
text-decoration: none;
}

.alertmdLLC {
text-align: center;
font: helvetica;
font-size: 12px;
letter-spacing: 1px;
font-weight: lighter;
vertical-align: top;
margin-bottom: 0px;
margin-top: 50px;
margin-left: 0px;
margin-right: 0px;
background-color: #dddddd;
color: gray;
}
/*  Footer end */


Here is the HTML
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>AlertMD</title>
  <link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>


 <!-- Start Navigation -->
 <header>
 <div class="container">
 <div class="logo-box">
   <a href="home.html">
     <img src="./images/logo.png" height="55px" width="250px">
   </a>
  </div>
  <nav>
  <ul>
   <li><a href="home.html">HOME</a></li>
   <li><a href="solutions.html">SOLUTIONS</a></li>
   <li><a href="about.html">ABOUT</a></li>
   <li><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>
 </ul>
 </nav>
 </div>
  </header>
  <!-- End Navigation -->


  <!-- Start Hero Image -->
  <div class="heroImage">
     <div class="heroText">
        <h2></h2>
        <p></p>
        <p id="heroTextButtons"><a href="contact.html" 
 class="learnMoreText" >
        Request a Demo ></a></p>
        <p id="heroTextButtons"><a href="solutions.html" 
 class="learnMoreText" >
        Learn More ></a></p>
     </div>
  </div>
  <!-- End Hero Image -->


  <!-- Start Why Choose Us -->
  <div class="whyChooseUs">
     <h2>Why Choose Us?</h2>
     <p></p>
  </div>
  <div class="solutionTable">
     <table>
        <tr>
           <th><img src="" alt="" height="100" width="75"> </th>
           <th><img src="" alt="" height="100" width="65"> </th>
           <th><img src="" alt="" height="100" width="100"> </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <th><h3></h3></th>
           <th><h3></h3></th>
           <th><h3></h3></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td></td>
           <td></td>
           <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>
              <a href="solutions.html">
              <img src="./images/LearnMoreBtn.png" alt="Learn More 
  Button" style="width:100px; height:auto;"></a>
            </td>
           <td>
              <a href="solutions.html">
              <img src="./images/LearnMoreBtn.png" alt="Learn More 
  Button" style="width:100px; height:auto;"></a>
           </td>
           <td>
              <a href="solutions.html">
              <img src="./images/LearnMoreBtn.png" alt="Learn More 
   Button" style="width:100px; height:auto;"></a>
           </td>
        </tr>
     </table>
  </div>
  <!-- End Why Choose Us -->


  <!-- Start Featured Clients -->
  <div class="featuredClients">
    <div id="meetTheTeam">
      <h2 class="decorated"><span>Featured Clients</span></h2>
    </div>
     <div class="images">
        <a href="" target="_blank">
        <img src="" alt="" style="width:300px; height:auto;"></a>
     </div>
     <div class="images">
        <a href="" target="_blank">
        <img src="" alt="" style="width:250px; height:auto;"></a>
     </div>
     <div class="images">
        <a href="" target="_blank">
        <img src="" alt="" style="width:250px; height:auto;"></a>
     </div>
     <div class="images">
        <a href="" target="_blank">
        <img src="" alt="" style="width:325px; height:auto;"></a>
     </div>
     <div class="images">
        <a href="" target="_blank">
        <img src="g" alt="" style="width:200px; height:auto;"></a>
     </div>
     <div class="images">
        <a href="" target="_blank">
        <img src="" alt="" style="width:200px; height:auto;"></a>
     </div>
     <div class="images">
        <a href="" target="_blank">
        <img src="" alt="" style="width:200px; height:auto;"></a>
     </div>
     <div class="images">
        <a href="" target="_blank">
        <img src="" alt="" style="width:250px; height:auto;"></a>
     </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Start Featured Clients -->


  <!-- Start Find Out -->
  <div class="findOut">
     <p>Find Out How  Can Improve Your Care Coordination</p>
     <div>
        <p><a href="contact.html" class="learnMoreText" >
        Request a Demo ></a></p>
     </div>
  </div>
  <!-- End Find Out -->


  <div id="footer">
 <div id="footerContainer">
    <div id="col1">
       <!-- Column one start -->
       <p class="nav">Navigation</p>
       <ul>
          <li><a href='home.html'>Home</a></li>
          <li><a href='about.html'>About</a></li>
          <li><a href='solutions.html'>Solutions</a></li>
          <li><a href='contact.html'>Contact</a></li>
       </ul>
       <!-- Column one end -->
    </div>
    <div id="col2">
       <!-- Column two start -->
       <p class="nav">Download Links</p>
       <ul>
          <li>
             <a href="" target="_blank">
             <img src="./images/appStore.png" alt="Apple App Store
  Download Icon" style="width:150px; height: 45px;"></a>
          </li>
          <li>
             <a href="" target="_blank">
             <img src="./images/playStore.png" alt="Google Play
  Store Download Icon" style="width:150px; height: 45px;"></a>
          </li>
       </ul>
       <!-- Column two end -->
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="alertmdLLC">
 <p>Copyright © 2017. All rights reserved.</p>
  </div>
  <!-- End Footer -->


   </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **CSS Flexbox** on `#footerContainer` to keep them side-by-side and remove the `float` property. Also assign columns `flex: 1;`, like:

```
#footerContainer {
  display: flex;
}

#col1 {
  flex: 1;
  padding: 0 15px;
  position:relative;
  text-align: left;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#col2 {
  flex: 1;
  padding: 0 15px;
  position:relative;
  background-color: #dddddd; /* column 2 background color */
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Have a look at the snippet below:

```css
body, html{
font-family: helvetica;
height:100%;
margin:0%;
}

header {
padding: 20px 0;
background: white;
}

.container {
padding: 0 30px 00px 30px;
max-width: 1600px; /* look on big monitor for width */
margin-right: 20px;
}

.logo-box {
float: left;
}

.logo-box a {
outline: none;
display: inline-block;
}

.logo-box img {display: inline;}
nav {
overflow: hidden;
}

ul {
list-style: none;
margin: 0;
padding-top: 30px;
padding-bottom: 0px;
float: right;
}

nav li {
display: inline-block;
margin-left: 25px;
height: 20px;
line-height: 20px;
transition: .5s linear;
}

nav a {
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
position: relative;
color: black;
font-size: 12px;
font-weight: lighter;
text-transform: uppercase;
}

nav a:after {
content: "";
width:0;
height: 7.5px;
position: absolute;
left: 0;
bottom: 0px;
background: black;
transition: width .3s linear;
}

nav a:hover:after {
width: 100%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 660px) {
header {text-align: center;}
.logo-box {
float: none;
display: inline-block;
margin: 0 0 0 0;
}
ul {float: none;}
nav li:first-of-type {margin-right: 0;}
}

@media screen and (max-width: 550px) {
nav {overflow: visible;}
nav li {
display: block;
margin: 0;
height: 40px;
line-height: 40px;
}
nav li:hover {text-decoration: underline;}
nav a:after {content: none;}
}

.heroImage {
background-image: url("./images/doc_tablet2.jpeg");
background-position: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
border-top: 1px solid gray;
position: relative;
width: 100%;
height: 70%;
display: table;
}

.heroText {
margin-top: 160px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
width: 70%;
text-align: center;
padding: 20px;
border-radius: 5px;
border-width: medium;
left: 0;
font-family: helvetica;
font-weight: lighter;
font-size: 20px;
color: #333;
letter-spacing: 1px;
display:block;
}

#heroTextButtons {
display: inline-block;
padding: 20px;
text-align: center;
font-size: 1px;
font: helvetica;
font-weight: lighter;
text-align: center;
color: #2D71C5;
}


/* End main image section */

/* Why choose us section start */
.whyChooseUs {
margin-left: 25px;
padding: 10px 40px;
height: auto;
width: auto;
color: #333;
letter-spacing: 1px;
line-height: 30px;
position: relative;
text-align: center;
outline: none;
font-size: 18px;
display: block;
font-weight: lighter;
}
/* Why choose us section end */

/* Solution table start */
.solutionTable {
table-layout: fixed;
margin-bottom: 60px;
padding: auto;
height: auto;
width: 100%;
color: #333;
letter-spacing: 1px;
line-height: 25px;
position: relative;
text-align: center;
font-size: 18px;
overflow:auto;
display: block;
border-collapse: separate;
border-spacing: 2px;
}

.solutionTable th, td {
table-layout: fixed;
text-align: center;
color: #333;
letter-spacing: 1px;
font-size: 16px;
font-weight: lighter;
vertical-align: top;
width: auto;
padding: 5px 40px 0px 0px;
overflow: auto;
}

/* End of Why Choose Us */

/* Featured Clients Section #FAFAFA*/
.featuredClients {
text-align: center;
background-color: white;
border-radius: 0px;
width: 100%;
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: top;
border-top: solid;
border-bottom: solid;
border-color: #e9e9e9;
border-width: thin;
font-weight: lighter;
}

#featuredClientsText {
font: helvetica;
font-size: 35px;
color: #333;
font-weight:lighter, bold;
letter-spacing: 1px;
text-align: center;
padding: 30px;
margin-top: 20px;
}

.decorated {
 overflow: hidden;
 text-align: center;
 font-weight:100;
 }
.decorated > span{
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
}
.decorated > span:before, .decorated > span:after{
content: '';
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
border-bottom: 2px solid;
width: 150px; /* half of limiter */
margin: 0 20px;
}
.decorated > span:before{
right: 100%;
}
.decorated > span:after{
left: 100%;
}
.images{
text-align: center;
vertical-align: top;
display: inline-block;
padding: 20px;
}

/* End Featured Clients Section */
.findOut {
text-align: center;
color: #333;
font: helvetica;
font-size: 35px;
font-weight: lighter;
letter-spacing: 1px;
letter-spacing: 1px;
background-color: white;
padding: 60px 60px 70px 50px;
width: auto;
border-bottom-style: solid;
border-color: #333;
border-width: medium;
position: relative;
line-height: 50px;
background-color: #FAFAFA;
border-bottom-style: solid;
border-color: #333;
}

.learnMoreText{
font-size: 20px;
font: helvetica;
font-weight: lighter;
text-align: center;
color: #0070c9;

}
.learnMoreText:hover {
text-decoration: underline;
text-align: center;
}
/* Find Out How Section */

/*  Footer start */
#footerContainer {
display: flex;
width:100%;
position:relative;
padding-top: 15px;
background-color: #dddddd; /* column 1 background color */
}

.nav {
font-size: 18px;
text-align: left;
font-family: helvetica;
margin-left: 40px;
letter-spacing: 1.5px;
color: #333;
margin: 0 0 10px;
}

#col1 {
flex: 1;
position:relative;
text-align: left;
text-decoration: none;
}

#col1, #col2 {
  padding: 0 30px;
}

#col1 ul,
#col2 ul {
  float: none;
  padding: 0;
}

#col1 ul, li, a {
font-size: 12px;
line-height: 25px;
text-decoration: none;
color: black;
letter-spacing: 1px;
}

#col1 a:hover {
color: black;
text-decoration: underline;
}

#col2 {
flex: 1;
position:relative;
background-color: #dddddd; /* column 2 background color */
text-decoration: none;
}

#col2 ul {
font-size: 20px;
text-align: left;
color: black;
text-decoration: none;
}

#col2 li {
font-size: 20px;
text-align: left;
display: inline-block;
text-decoration: none;
}

.alertmdLLC {
text-align: center;
font: helvetica;
font-size: 12px;
letter-spacing: 1px;
font-weight: lighter;
vertical-align: top;
margin-bottom: 0px;
padding-top: 50px;
padding-bottom: 15px;
margin-left: 0px;
margin-right: 0px;
background-color: #dddddd;
color: gray;
}

.alertmdLLC p {
  margin: 0;
}
/*  Footer end */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>AlertMD</title>
  <link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>


 <!-- Start Navigation -->
<header>
<div class="container">
<div class="logo-box">
 <a href="home.html">
   <img src="./images/logo.png" height="55px" width="250px">
 </a>
</div>
<nav>
<ul>
 <li><a href="home.html">HOME</a></li>
 <li><a href="solutions.html">SOLUTIONS</a></li>
 <li><a href="about.html">ABOUT</a></li>
 <li><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
</div>
</header>
<!-- End Navigation -->


<!-- Start Hero Image -->
<div class="heroImage">
   <div class="heroText">
      <h2></h2>
      <p></p>
      <p id="heroTextButtons"><a href="contact.html" 
class="learnMoreText" >
      Request a Demo ></a></p>
      <p id="heroTextButtons"><a href="solutions.html" 
class="learnMoreText" >
      Learn More ></a></p>
   </div>
</div>
<!-- End Hero Image -->


<!-- Start Why Choose Us -->
<div class="whyChooseUs">
   <h2>Why Choose Us?</h2>
   <p></p>
</div>
<div class="solutionTable">
   <table>
      <tr>
         <th><img src="" alt="" height="100" width="75"> </th>
         <th><img src="" alt="" height="100" width="65"> </th>
         <th><img src="" alt="" height="100" width="100"> </th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <th><h3></h3></th>
         <th><h3></h3></th>
         <th><h3></h3></th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>
            <a href="solutions.html">
            <img src="./images/LearnMoreBtn.png" alt="Learn More 
Button" style="width:100px; height:auto;"></a>
          </td>
         <td>
            <a href="solutions.html">
            <img src="./images/LearnMoreBtn.png" alt="Learn More 
Button" style="width:100px; height:auto;"></a>
         </td>
         <td>
            <a href="solutions.html">
            <img src="./images/LearnMoreBtn.png" alt="Learn More 
 Button" style="width:100px; height:auto;"></a>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </table>
</div>
<!-- End Why Choose Us -->


<!-- Start Featured Clients -->
<div class="featuredClients">
  <div id="meetTheTeam">
    <h2 class="decorated"><span>Featured Clients</span></h2>
  </div>
   <div class="images">
      <a href="" target="_blank">
      <img src="" alt="" style="width:300px; height:auto;"></a>
   </div>
   <div class="images">
      <a href="" target="_blank">
      <img src="" alt="" style="width:250px; height:auto;"></a>
   </div>
   <div class="images">
      <a href="" target="_blank">
      <img src="" alt="" style="width:250px; height:auto;"></a>
   </div>
   <div class="images">
      <a href="" target="_blank">
      <img src="" alt="" style="width:325px; height:auto;"></a>
   </div>
   <div class="images">
      <a href="" target="_blank">
      <img src="g" alt="" style="width:200px; height:auto;"></a>
   </div>
   <div class="images">
      <a href="" target="_blank">
      <img src="" alt="" style="width:200px; height:auto;"></a>
   </div>
   <div class="images">
      <a href="" target="_blank">
      <img src="" alt="" style="width:200px; height:auto;"></a>
   </div>
   <div class="images">
      <a href="" target="_blank">
      <img src="" alt="" style="width:250px; height:auto;"></a>
   </div>
</div>
<!-- Start Featured Clients -->


<!-- Start Find Out -->
<div class="findOut">
   <p>Find Out How  Can Improve Your Care Coordination</p>
   <div>
      <p><a href="contact.html" class="learnMoreText" >
      Request a Demo ></a></p>
   </div>
</div>
<!-- End Find Out -->


<div id="footer">
<div id="footerContainer">
  <div id="col1">
     <!-- Column one start -->
     <p class="nav">Navigation</p>
     <ul>
        <li><a href='home.html'>Home</a></li>
        <li><a href='about.html'>About</a></li>
        <li><a href='solutions.html'>Solutions</a></li>
        <li><a href='contact.html'>Contact</a></li>
     </ul>
     <!-- Column one end -->
  </div>
  <div id="col2">
     <!-- Column two start -->
     <p class="nav">Download Links</p>
     <ul>
        <li>
           <a href="" target="_blank">
           <img src="./images/appStore.png" alt="Apple App Store
Download Icon" style="width:150px; height: 45px;"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
           <a href="" target="_blank">
           <img src="./images/playStore.png" alt="Google Play
Store Download Icon" style="width:150px; height: 45px;"></a>
        </li>
     </ul>
     <!-- Column two end -->
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="alertmdLLC">
<p>Copyright © 2017. All rights reserved.</p>
</div>
<!-- End Footer -->


 </body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hmm... for some reason that didn't work. They ended up floating below one another. Thanks though, will keep chipping away.

Comment: Can you host the code anywhere, so that I can check?

Comment: I just added the entire html and css - thanks again for your help, it is greatly appreciated!

Comment: @AKentgen Please have a look at my updated code. I hope this should work. Please let me know.

Comment: @AKentgen It's my pleasure. Please accept this answer if this helped you out.

Answer (score 0):

Change some of your css to:

```
.container {
    padding: 0 30px 0px 30px;
    max-width: 1600px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
.logo-box {
    float: left;
    height: 55px;
}
ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    /* padding-top: 30px; */
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    float: right;
 }
```

[image]

Hope this helps!